# Distinguishability of particles in statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Historically,how,and by what experiments,the concept of identical and distinguishable particles was discovered?Is it a tagline set by scientists,or nature indeed works in this way?

Comment: Do you mean discovering distinguishability or *in*distinguishability? It seems the former was traditionally the default assumption, whereas the latter is now attributed to Gibbs in solving his “paradox” — although this wasn't fully appreciated until later: see e.g. Katz ([1967](//google.com/books?id=pQqYxlzLy2EC), Chap. 7), Souriau ([1967](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0152.46204), §6; [1970](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1461545), [17.169](http://www.jmsouriau.com/structure_des_systemes_dynamiques.htm)), Saunders  ([2013](//arxiv.org/abs/1609.05504), §2.1; [2018](//doi.org/10.3390/e20080552), §2.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discovery was made in trying to explain the spectrum of black body radiation, using statistical mechanics. See Wikipedia articles on 
[History of Bose-Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#History) and
[Ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe).